# How to fill width of last column at DevExpress GridControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress, gridcontrol

I have DevExpress GridControl which has 7 columns.
I tried to expand the last column to the right, but nothing happens.
Instead, the column stretches for some distance, and on the right edge of the grid, there is an empty column with no name, which can not be stretched.

So, I try to google it: I find some answers like [this](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q446483), but it does not work for me.

Here some peace of XAML, I remove all bindings.

```xml
<dxg:GridControl Grid.Row="0"
                x:Name="dgGrid"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                dx:ThemeManager.ThemeName="Seven"

                ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                >

    <dxg:GridControl.View>
        <!--region #RowCellMenuCustomization-->
        <dxg:TableView x:Name="view" AutoWidth="True" NavigationStyle="Cell">
            <dxg:TableView.RowCellMenuCustomizations>
                <dxb:BarButtonItem Content="Link"
                                ItemClick="CellDataItem_Link_ItemClick"
                                ></dxb:BarButtonItem>

                <dxb:BarButtonItem Content="UnLink"
                                ItemClick="CellDataItem_UnLink_ItemClick"
                                ></dxb:BarButtonItem>
            </dxg:TableView.RowCellMenuCustomizations>
        </dxg:TableView>
        <!--endregion #RowCellMenuCustomization-->
    </dxg:GridControl.View>

    <dxg:GridControl.Columns>

        <dxg:GridColumn Header="Column0"
                    AllowEditing="False"
                    HorizontalHeaderContentAlignment="Stretch"
                    FixedWidth="True"
                    AllowResizing="True"
                    MinWidth="80"
                    ></dxg:GridColumn>

        <dxg:GridColumn Header="Column1"
                    AllowEditing="False"
                    HorizontalHeaderContentAlignment="Stretch"
                    FixedWidth="True"
                    AllowResizing="True"
                    MinWidth="80"
                    ></dxg:GridColumn>

        <dxg:GridColumn Header="Column2"
                    AllowEditing="False"
                    HorizontalHeaderContentAlignment="Stretch"
                    AllowResizing="True"
                    FixedWidth="True"
                    Visible="False"
                    MinWidth="80"
                    ></dxg:GridColumn>

        <dxg:GridColumn Header="Column3"
                    HorizontalHeaderContentAlignment="Center"
                    AllowEditing="False"
                    Width="35"
                    FixedWidth="True"
                    AllowResizing="False"
                    ></dxg:GridColumn>

        <dxg:GridColumn Header="Column4"
                    HorizontalHeaderContentAlignment="Center"
                    FixedWidth="True"
                    AllowEditing="False"
                    AllowResizing="False"
                    Width="35"
                    ></dxg:GridColumn>

        <dxg:GridColumn Header="Column5"
                    HorizontalHeaderContentAlignment="Stretch"
                    FixedWidth="True"
                    AllowEditing="False"
                    AllowResizing="True"
                    MinWidth="170"
                    ></dxg:GridColumn>

        <dxg:GridColumn Header="Column6"
                    HorizontalHeaderContentAlignment="Stretch"
                    AllowEditing="False"
                    AllowResizing="True"
                    Width="*"
                    Fixed="None"
                    BestFitMode="Default"
                    BestFitArea="All"
                    MinWidth="130"
                    FixedWidth="False"
                    />

    </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
</dxg:GridControl>
```

[image: Here example of my GridControl]

At the same time, I use `BestFit` method, which works when GridControl loaded:

```
private void Grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ((TableView)this.view).BestFitArea = BestFitArea.All;
    var visibleColumns = ((TableView)this.view).VisibleColumns;
    ((TableView)this.view).BestFitColumns();
}
```

Please, can you help me to fit last column (Column6) width to the end of the grid?

Comment: Is There any autogenerateColumns dependency property?
If there is then you can set It To false and  check.

Comment: @AbhinavSharma, bo, i do not use any AutogenerateColumns property. My names is not like 'Column0' it is like: Name,City and so on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`TableView.AutoWidth`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridTableView_AutoWidthtopic) property is what you are looking for. You have already set it, but there is error in your `Column6`. The `Width` of column cannot be set to `"*"`. So, I used your code, removed `Width="*"` and here is the result:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

In fact, if you are using **16.1 or a newer version**, setting "*" as a column width should work properly. I have created a test project based on your code and snippet:[image]

The use of '*' in the GridColumn.Width property enables the **Proportional column sizing** feature, however it's not available in old versions. To learn more about this feature, please refer to [Columns Layout and Width](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument6296).

If you have an older version, enable the [AutoWidth](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridTableView_AutoWidthtopic) option.

Comment: I have 16.2 version

Comment: @Admiral Land, I have created a test project based on your description and it seems that the last column is properly stretched. It's strange that this code doesn't work on your side.